# Add hidden shortcode by default on all product posts

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I was wondering if there is a way to add hidden shortcode to every Woocommerce's product post? And how would I do that?

Shortcode is: `[customer_list]`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it for you:

```
<div style="display:none;">
    <?php echo do_shortcode('[customer_list]'); ?>    
</div>
```

You can use `<?php echo do_shortcode('[customer_list]'); ?>` within the div wrapper if you are editing the `content-product.php` template or any other that is used directly on the product page.

Comment: Hey thanks for this! Is it possible to add it from functions.php file?